# Calling storyboard from UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, storyboard

I don't know if this is possible or not but I wrote a project using xibs and want to modally switch to a storyboard project.

I know that to switch VC's you do something like

```
NewViewController *NewVC = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:NewVC animated:YES];
```

upon clicking a button, that I'll call "switch"

There is another project using solely storyboards that I want to call using "switch"

How do I go about doing this? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Look for `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. And please, use lowercase for the first letter of your variables (here NewVC to newVC).

Comment: Thank you, will do in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can do something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
MainMenuViewController *mainmenuvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainmenuvc animated:YES];
```

**EDIT**
If I understand your comment, you want to change the root view controller. You can do so by:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RVCStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MainMenuViewController *mainmenuvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuViewController"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate].window.rootViewController = mainmenuvc;
```

Please note that for this to work, in your RVCStoryboard you have to select the viewcontroller you are trying to load, and assign a name to it so that the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method will work. Check the attached image, the field "Storyboard ID":
 [image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think I should have been more clear. I have a VC, RootViewControlller that I want to go to which is using the my storyboard RVCStoryboard.storyboard. If I can get the code you put working correctly, does this go from the VC (which is xib) the "switch" button is on to RootViewController/RVCStoryboard?

Comment: The storyboard contains a navigation controller nad a root view controller with a table view inside of it. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Note: If the two view controllers reside in the same storyboard, you can simply use the `self.storyboard` in the view controller that's instantiating the other one. `self.storyboard` refers to the storyboard that the view controller originates from.